# Cálculo de horas dentro da consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu já fiz essa conta e funciona certinho em C++. O meu problema é fazer dentro de um *select* para aparecer na tabela. Se alguém quiser ver o algoritmo em C++ para auxiliar a montar no MySql posso mandar.

A minha tabela é essa:

[image: SELECT MYSQL]

Os campos depois do state são custom_fields criados por mim

Eu preciso criar mais 4 fields. 
•   O tempo total que o state está em 0. 
•   O tempo total que o state está acima de 0. 
•   A porcentagem que ele ficou em 0 e outro. 
•   A porcentagem que o state ficou acima de 0.

Como podem ver só aparece a o tempo que o state mudou. Então eu preciso pegar o tempo do state e subtrair pelo tempo do state anterior diferente. Se tiver duas linhas com o mesmo state, considera só o tempo da primeira linha do state repetido a ser subtraído. O resultado dessas subtrações serão somadas e gerarão um tempo total no final.

Na última linha, tenho que pegar o total do tempo e subtrair do tempo atual, pois a última linha da consulta é o state atual.

O cálculo das horas e porcentagens deverão estar separadas por object_id.

No final tenho que agrupar a tabela por object_id para trazer na jqgrid da tela.

Se eu não fui bem claro, podem comentar, tentarei explicar melhor.

Eu estava pensando que uma solução boa seria usar variáveis e funções, mas como eu sou novo não tenho muito conhecimento disso. Se alguém souber de alguma apostila ou curso que explique bem sobre esses assuntos, pode indicar.

Answer (score 2):

Para o tempo total que o state está em 0 (use a mesma lógica para quando o *state* for diferente de zero), você pode usar o [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN `state` = 0 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `current_time`, `state_time` ELSE 0 END) AS `state_zero` FROM `minha_tabela`
```

Para o tempo, em percentagem, em que o *state* ficou em zero (use a mesma lógica para os demais cálculos de porcentagem), você pode usar algo assim:

```sql
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN `state` = 0
        THEN
            CONCAT(ROUND((COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `minha_tabela`)*100),2),'%')
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `porcentagem_zero`
FROM `minha_tabela`
```

Usei [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para concatenar o resultado da porcentagem com o símbolo "%" (percentagem).

Usei [ROUND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) para arredondar o argumento (valor da porcentagem) para 2 (duas) casas decimais, porque, na maioria dos casos, percentagens com mais de 2 (duas) casa decimais são insignificantes ([algarismos significativos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algarismo_significativo)).

**Consideração:**

Para os casos em que a tabela estiver vazia, considere tratar o caso de divisão por zero.

Comment: Olá Victor. A imagem da tabela está abrindo? O que eu preciso na verdade é somar todos os tempos que o state está em zero e todos os tempos que o state está diferente de zero e mostrar o resultado total de cada um. E depois a porcentagem do tempo que o state estava em 0 e maior que  0.